# Toggling character in div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would expect the following code to toggle the html content of `.articleArrow` between up and down arrows when `.articleTitle` is clicked:

**jQuery**

```
$(".articleTitle").click(function () {
    if ($(this).children('.articleArrow').html() == '&#8593;')
        $(this).children('.articleArrow').html('&#8595;');
    else if ($(this).children('.articleArrow').html() == '&#8595;')
        $(this).children('.articleArrow').html('&#8593;');
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='articleTitle'>
    Blah
    <div class='articleArrow'>
        &#8595;
    </div>
</div>
```

But it doesn't do anything. On the other hand if I take the `if...else if` out and just set the character with `$(this).children('.articleArrow').html('&#8593;');` it works. So setting the character works it's the `if...else` if that's not getting triggered properly and I can't figure out why.

[You can view it live on my website here](http://rlcoaching.com/admin.php) (don't get excited it's not the actual admin panel!)

Comment: So you want the arrow character to switch when pressed? (up arrow and down arrow)

Comment: @Austin Yes, I want it to toggle between up and down when the parent div is clicked

Comment: Once the HTML entities is inserted into the DOM the entities are parsed and are no longer entities, so `html()` doesn't return entities, which you could have figured out by logging your values to the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do with this without the messy `if statement` by simply making use of the [`.slideToggle`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)'s [complete callback method](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/#callback-function) and jQuery's [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector.

```
$(".articleTitle").click(function () {
    //  1st, i go ahead and asign our arrow element to a variable for use in callback
    var arrow = $(this).find('.articleArrow');
    $(this).siblings('.articleContent').slideToggle("slow", function(){
        //  this is the `complete` callback method
        //  in here, we can now manipulate whatever we need to when the "toggle" is `complete`
        arrow.html( $(this).is(':visible') ? '&#8593;' : '&#8595;' );
        //  inside the .html statement is a simple `inline if` statement that simply says:
        //      if true ? do this : else do this
    });
});
```

## Example

[<sub>Behind the `show`</sub>](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/ta9xr)

---

Plain Code:

```
$(".articleTitle").click(function () {
    var a = $(this).find(".articleArrow");
    $(this).siblings(".articleContent").slideToggle("slow", function () {
        a.html($(this).is(":visible") ? "&#8593;" : "&#8595;")
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks learned something new! I'm new to jQuery but if I understand correctly, the check for ':visible' is just something that returns *true* (if it's visible of course). But I could replace that by just 'true', or anything else that returns true? The visible check serves no other purpose here no?

Comment: @Juicy the visible check here serves purpose in deciding if the element is toggle open or close. If it's closed, then it's not visible. You could replace it with anything, but I'm not sure how anything else would fit what you're wanting to achieve here?

Answer (score 2):

Works for me if I use the unicode characters to compare to:

```
$(".articleTitle").click(function () {
    if ($(this).children('.articleArrow').html() == '↓') $(this).children('.articleArrow').html('&#8593;');
    else if ($(this).children('.articleArrow').html() == '↑') $(this).children('.articleArrow').html('&#8595;');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Wf52F/)**